# FreeRADIUS VLAN assignment from Open Directory group

Tags: osx, radius, freeradius

I'd like to authenticate and assign WiFi users to different VLANs determined by their Apple Open Directory group. FreeRADIUS has an [Open Directory module](https://networkradius.com/doc/3.0.10/raddb/mods-available/opendirectory.html), however I can't find much information about it.

Is it possible to assign a VLAN from a user's group using Open Directory and FreeRADIUS?

Comment: It is, but it is not simple. Please do tell us what you have done until now, and how we can improve it. The question is too vague and broad as it is.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I haven't done anything yet, I'm just seeing if it's plausible to attempt it before committing to anything. Do you have any details about implementation or any information about the open directory module?

Comment: Not really, I am more familiar with AD/LDAP